# DataGrid append another column sort

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF project - a datagrid with four columns: ColumnOne, ColumnTwo, columnThree, ColumnFour. Is it possible that when user sorts by ColumnOne or ColumnTwo - then code behind adds sorting by ColumnThree as well, so it gets sorted like SortBy("ColumnOne").ThenBy("ColumnThree"). If that matters, ItemsSource for my DataGrid is PagedCollectionView, which supports SortDescriptors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override [DataGrid.OnSorting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.onsorting(v=vs.110).aspx) like in this simple example (but please *extend* it to your *full* requirements) and use the *custom* control instead of the standard `DataGrid` in your XAML.

```
public class MyDataGrid : DataGrid
    {
        protected override void OnSorting(DataGridSortingEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            base.OnSorting(eventArgs);
            var test = eventArgs.Column;
            if (test.Header.ToString() == "ColumnOne" && test.SortDirection.HasValue
                && test.SortDirection.Value.Equals(ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                )
            {
                ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.ItemsSource);
                view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("ColumnThree", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                view.Refresh();

                this.Columns[2].SortDirection = ListSortDirection.Ascending;
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code handles both the colletion sorting and the `SortDirection` property setting for `ColumnThree` in just one case: when the user orders by `ColumnOne` ascending.